# How do I count all occurrences of a particular string in a file using a batch file?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f %%C in ('Find /C "pdf" ^< %CD%\sample.txt') do set Count=%%C
    echo Found = !Count! time/s >> xerox.log
    echo Found = %%C time/s

pause
```

That's my batch file. It finds and counts the word "pdf" throughout the file, but it counts per line. It does not count all the occurrences. How do I count all of it?

Comment: [may be relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584806/in-a-batch-file-how-to-find-the-occurrences-of-string-in-a-textfile)

Comment: I can't comprehend what's in there sorry. Would you point out what codes to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How do I find all occurences of the word "pdf" in a file?

Use the following batch file.

**test.cmd**

```
@echo off
setlocal
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set _count=0
set _match=pdf
set _file=abc.txt

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (%_file%) do (
  set _line=%%i
  call :match
  )
 goto :done
  
:match
  for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ("%_line%") do (
    set _word=%%a
    set _line=%%b
  )
  if /i "%_word%"=="%_match%" set /a _count=!_count!+1
  if "%_line%"=="" goto :eof
goto :match

:done
echo."pdf" was found !_count! times.

endlocal
```

- Replace `abc.txt` with the filename containing your txt.
- Replace `echo."pdf" was found !_count! times.` with your own `echo` commands as appropriate.

**abc.txt**

```
abc pdf def pdf
pdf
pdf pdf pdf
abc def ghi
```

**example usage**

```
F:\test>test
"pdf" was found 6 times.

F:\test>
```

---

#### what if the txt file is like this `abc.pdf def.pdf pdf pdf pdf pdf abc def ghi` It only counts 4

In this case the second `for /f` command need to be changed to use both `.` and   (the default) as delimeters for the matching.

Here is the replacement line:

```
  for /f "tokens=1,* delims=. " %%a in ("%_line%") do (
```

`delims=.`  has been added.

---

#### Further reading

- [for](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) - Conditionally perform a command several times
- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.

Comment: Thanks! It's working! :) But I got a question, what if the txt file is like this

abc.pdf def.pdf
pdf
pdf pdf pdf
abc def ghi

It only counts 4, can it be modified to count also the other two? Sorry if I'm a bit of a nuisance to you.

Comment: @greyMatter Yes. We need to change the second `for /f` to match `.` and ` `. I have updated the answer.